# Memory barriers, unsure if I can use relaxed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

Using pseudo code I have two threads both trying to reach and "pop" the same data first:

Thread1

```
DataBlock db = memoryLocationX.reserveBlock();
```

Thread2

```
DataBlock anotherDB = memoryLocationX.reserveBlock();
```

and `reserveBlock()` performs an std::exchange() on the memory, returning the original value and replacing it with a blank value, so only one thread can obtain the data:

```
DataBlock reserveBlock(){
    return DataBlock(_internalState.exchange(EMPTY_VALUE));
}
```

My question is, under what circumstances can I use `std::memory_order_relaxed` as second argument to `exchange()`? All I am trying to ensure is that only one of the threads retrieves the data stored within _internalState. But this is achieved already with exchange(), so does this mean I can use `std::memory_order_relaxed`?

Comment: The words "memory order barriers" don't mean anything.

Comment: [`std::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) is not what you think it may be. You may have been thinking of [`std::atomic_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange).

Comment: Relaxed ordering doesn't make sense with read-modify-write (RMW) operations. RMW operations enjoy a special status in the memory model.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have an atomic variable and the member method on it is just .exchange()? Yes, I do mean atomic exchange, but there's no "_atomic" bit preceding it.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you elaborate on your third message, this is probably answering my question?

Comment: Not in a comment :-) Read 1.10? It explains how RMW operations fit into release sequences and supply synchronization.

Comment: @user997112, if you're talking about the member function [`std::atomic<T>::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange) then that is not "std::exchange()" as you wrote above. [`std::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) is a free function and not related to atomics.

Comment: If you're unsure then you should not be using relaxed atomics. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `std::memory_order_relaxed` you get no guarantees, only that there will be no data races. It avoids undefined behaviour but there are few situations where it is really useful (e.g., if you can guarantee synchronization by other ways).

In your example, you need to synchronize between threads, so if you use relaxed semantics, you would still need to synchronize explicitely anyway. Otherwise, it is not guaranteed that the other threads sees the modification.

In the end, it will most likely not be faster and the code will be more complicated.

Comment: @user997112 Once the first thread gets the data and writes the empty value, the second thread has to see the change once it calls reserveBlock. In the C++ memory model, the first thread has to "release" the memory and the second one has to "aquire" it, so it will be synchronized. In the relaxed ordering, that does not happen. So, the second thread may reserve the same block as the first block (--> race condition).

Comment: Ah I understand, we need to flush the "result" out to all other cores.